# How to allow input type=file to accept only images files in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, safari

I have this:

```
<input class="inline" id="imgInput" name='imgInput' type="file" ng-file-select="saveImage($files)" accept="image/*" data-ng-model="inputImage">
```

It works in Mozilla and Chrome, but in Safari I can choose any kind of file. How can I get the input to accept only image files in Safari?

Comment: Welcome to the world of web development where the browsers have different capabilities. Your server side code is going to have to do it's own validation of uploaded content (as it should be doing anyway).

Comment: FYI, support for that attribute started in Safari 6. So if you're using an older version it won't work there.

Comment: that´s right. I tested on Safari for Windows (Safari 5.1.7) so that is why it doesn't work. Thanks for your quick answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of a code I use to check if file is a picture.

```
<?php
if($_FILES['picture'] == '' OR empty($_FILES['picture']))
{
header("Location: picture.php?error=file");
}

elseif ($_FILES['picture']['error'] > 0) 
{
  if($_FILES['picture']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE)
     { header("Location: picture.php?error=file");}
  elseif($_FILES['picture']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE)
     { header("Location: picture.php?error=size");}
  elseif($_FILES['picture']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE)
     { header("Location: picture.php?error=size");}
  elseif($_FILES['picture']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL)
     { header("Location: picture.php?error=partial");} 
  else {
  header("Location: picture.php?error=file");
  }

}

  $imageSize = getimagesize($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']);
if($imageSize['mime'] == 'image/jpeg' OR $imageSize['mime'] == 'image/png' OR $imageSize['mime'] == 'image/gif')
{

$validExtensions = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
$extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['picture']['name'], '.'),1));

if (!in_array($extension,$validExtensions)) 
    { header("Location: picture.php?error=extension");}



if ($_FILES['picture']['size'] > 5242880)
       { header("Location: picture.php?error=size");}



if ($imageSize[0] > 5000 OR $imageSize[1] > 5000) 
       { header("Location: picture.php?error=size");}

//DO OTHER THINGS
}
else
{
header("Location: picture.php?error=type");
}

?>
```